# Value Error on a script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm an Amateur programmer. Everytime I run a script The message

> invalid literal for int() with base 10

comes.

The code is for making a dumchar_info file to a scatter.txt.

The  code is from [this site](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2540400)

```
import sys

import string

import re


ins = open( "dumchar.txt", "rb" )

outs = open( "scatter.txt", "wb" )

for line in ins:

    linesp = re.split('\W+', line)

    name = linesp[0].upper()

    start = int(linesp[2],16)

    block = linesp[5]

    if block != 'misc':

        start = start + 0x600000

    outs.write(name + " " + string.replace(hex(start), "L", "") + "\n{\n}\n")

ins.close()

outs.close()
```

Comment: Here is the link of the dumchar_info file                     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_THUoWuufO5Zmt3QU1ONlhMbzg/view?usp=docslist_api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within the file, because it starts out in the format that you're expecting, but as you continue reading it, the format changes in the last 5 lines. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
usrdata      0x000000013cc80000   0x0000000093300000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
bmtpool      0x0000000001500000   0x00000000febf00a8   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
Part_Name:Partition name you should open;
StartAddr:Start Address of partition;
Type:Type of partition(MTD=1,EMMC=2)
MapTo:actual device you operate
Size:size of partition
```

This is right where it changes from having the numbers you're looking for to having just descriptions (Part_Name:Partition name...).  You can either change the file to remove the last 5 lines or change your script so that it stops reading the file when it no longer has valid inputs.

You're also going to have to cut out the very first line with the headers, since that's messing up the formatting, too. So the line

```
Part_Name       Size    StartAddr       Type    MapTo
```

See denys.fridman's answer.

Comment: But i need the usrdata and bmtpool for the scatter and on there are only 4 lines

Comment: Not those 4 lines, the very last 5 lines in the file. They start at Part_Name and Size, and continue on to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that linesp[2] is not always in the format you expect it to be. As Kamal Sadek correctly pointed out, the issue is with the first and last five lines of the file, where linesp[2] is a not a hexadecimal number.

A way to solve this would be adding

```
if not linesp[2].startswith('0x'):
    continue
```

just before

```
start = int(linesp[2],16)
```